# Triple nested for loop?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I am currently working on a script that prints all numbers between 000 and 999.
I have tried something like this:

```
@echo off
set "nums=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0"
for %%a in (%nums%) do (
for %%b in (%nums%) do (
for %%c in (%nums%) do echo %%a%%b%%c
)
)
pause
```

But the output numbers are incomlete and in a strange order.
After hours of reflextion, I made this script:

```
@echo off
echo list of nums: > nums.txt
set fstnum=0
set secnum=0
set trdnum=0
goto astrt 
:strt:
set /a "fstnum=%fstnum% + 1"
:astrt:
echo %trdnum%%secnum%%fstnum% >> nums.txt
if /i %trdnum%==9 (if %secnum%==9 if %fstnum%==9 exit) else (goto next)
:next:
if /i %secnum%==9 (goto ak) else (goto nnxxtt)
:nnxxtt:
if /i %fstnum%==9 (goto nd) else (goto strt)
:nd:
set fstnum=0
set /a "secnum=%secnum% + 1"
goto astrt
:ak:
if /i %fstnum%==9 (goto nkst) else (goto strt)
:nkst:
set secnum=0
set fstnum=0
set /a "trdnum=%trdnum% + 1"
goto astrt
```

Now all works great, but I am wondering why the triple nested `for` loops did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Labels should be specified like `:Label` instead of `:Label:`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /l %%n in (0,1,999) do (
    set "num=00%%n"
    echo !num:~-3!
)
pause>nul
```

You can adjust numbers at your will.

This loop goes 0 to 999 with increment of 1, adds two zeros in front of the numbers and prints 3 right side digits.

The result will be 000 to 999 as you described.

Answer (score 1):

your loop performs exactly as declared. But the result might not be what you expected because of an incorrect initialization.

If you just change the `%nums%` declaration to

```
 set "nums=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
```

you will get the resulting strings in the usual cardinal order: 000, 001, 002, ... 998, 999.

Comment: right, but sometimes i get numbers like: 95 Ⓒ0 , 96 Ⓒ0 .... any ideas? (and it starts by 7 Ⓒ01 , i do not see numbers less than 701)

Comment: @HackR_360 - I take your exact code from your question, make the change that PA suggests, and then run, and I get the correct output. So you are doing something else wrong that you are not showing or telling us about.